# Will it produce alternating magnetic field with respect to time, if l hybrid soft magnet with self decaying(Radioactive) material?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electromagnetic-induction

Radioactive material emits electromagnetic waves (Gamma Ray).
Soft magents has low magnetic coercivity, Right.
Suppose if i hybrid very soft magnet alongside with strong radioactive material, will it produce alternating magnetic field?
If yes, how strong will it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, No.

Longer: gamma rays are of MeV energies. The magnetization of the material  is a solid state phenomenon of order of electron volts. The gamma will go right through the material, or interact with a nucleus. It will not see the long wavelength structure of the magnetic field.

In addition, gammas will be emitted randomly and in random directions,  so it would not work even if the previous paragraph were not true.